# Flash HTML5 Canvas clickthrough, failing Double Click QA

Tags: html, html5-canvas, double-click-advertising, flashcanvas

ive built an online ad using flash canvas and uploaded it to Double Click studio for publishing. All is great, however, it has failed QA because the clickthrough is activating on 'right button' mouse down too.

Anyone know how to remedy this? ie only have the Click registered for left button clicks?

here is my button code:

`this.bgExit.addEventListener("click", fl_MouseClickHandler_3.bind(this));
function fl_MouseClickHandler_3() {
    alert("Mouse clicked");
}`

any help gratefully appreciated!